# Pandas read_csv reads NaN as "" when using regex sep

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

When I provide a regex `sep` argument to `read_csv` such as `[,\t]` in the example below I get NaN values read as `""`. I suspect this might be a bug but am looking for advice on workarounds or someone to explain why it's not a bug. It seems to only happen if the DataFrame only has a single column

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file_path = "temp.csv"

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [np.nan, 1]})
df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
df1 = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=',')
df2 = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='[,\t]')

print(f"-----------\ndf1\n{df1}")
print(f"-----------\ndf2\n{df2}")
```

Output

```py
-----------
df1
     x
0  NaN
1  1.0
-----------
df2
     x
0   ""
1  1.0
```

Comment: It's not a bug, this is the correct behaviour. From the doc: "Note that regex delimiters are prone to ignoring quoted data." (for the 'python' engine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix it:

```
>>> pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='[,\t]', na_values='""', engine="python")
     x
0  NaN
1  1.0
```